# Java: Multithreaded complex Getter

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a get-method that Returns a non-primitive type, and should be thread-safe.

**Functional description**

I have an Operation working on a separate thread. This Operation Needs the IP-Address and gets it from an other class using my own getter-method (*because I have to do some IP-Address calculation*). The getter Returns an `InetAddress`.

**Code example**

```
// This is called in a separate thread.
// How can I make Utility.getMyIp() thread-safe?
InetAddress myIp = Utility.getMyIp();
```

**Question**

What do I have to note about the IP-Address getter method? I need to use the method from an other thread. Do I have to make it synchronized?

If you need more informations, please ask!

PS: There are other threads asking similar questions, but the ones I found talk only about primitive datatypes, on which should be enough to use the volatile Keyword. Here I need return a type `InetAddress`.

**EDIT: Added Code**

*This is work in Progress (it may not work in every case and is not finished-code).*

```
/**
 * Gets the BroadcastAddress for IPv4.
 * @return
 * @throws SocketException
 */
public static InetAddress getBroadcastAddress4() {

    // Todo: Check other possibility
    System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");

    // Init
    InetAddress broadcastAddress = null;

    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

        while(interfaces != null && interfaces.hasMoreElements()){
            NetworkInterface currentInterface = interfaces.nextElement();

            if(!currentInterface.isLoopback()){
                for(InterfaceAddress address : currentInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()){
                    InetAddress broadcast = address.getBroadcast();
                    if(broadcast != null){
                        broadcastAddress = broadcast;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return broadcastAddress;
}
```

Comment: Is `getMyIp` static?

Comment: Yes it is static, or if it's better (in relation to multithreaded) I could also instantiate Utility, but right now it is static.

Comment: I always though that reads are threadsafe....

Comment: @Antoniossss it depends. If you have a simple read that reads a primitive datatype, it might be (not completely!). The Problem is that my read does some calculations, is not atomic. The data could change and there could be concurrent Access to the different classes I am using.

Comment: Then it is not read - that is wy I wrote what I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is thread safe without any further modifications.

You could also store the result of this method to a variable and do the actual computation once - as the results are unlikely to change during the runtime of your program. Initialize the variable lazily or use a `static {}` code block to initialize it on classload. The code could look like this:

```
InetAddress broadcastAddress;

public static InetAddress getBroadcastAddress4() {
    return broadcastAddress;
}

static {
    System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");

    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

        while(interfaces != null && interfaces.hasMoreElements()){
            NetworkInterface currentInterface = interfaces.nextElement();

            if(!currentInterface.isLoopback()){
                for(InterfaceAddress address : currentInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()){
                    InetAddress broadcast = address.getBroadcast();
                    if(broadcast != null){
                        broadcastAddress = broadcast;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // log the damn exception!
        Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class).error("exception when getting broadcast address", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the System Properties I am Setting? And I am enumerating trough the NetworkInterfaces? No need for modifications? If this is true, I am happy. If you add an example for the static{} Code, we get an even better answer ;)

Comment: System properties setting may affect other places in the code, but the call itself is safe. Unless you change the same property elsewhere, you are safe. Enumerating and reading a collection is always safe, it's write operations that can cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the Code, your explanation makes sense.   
PS: The logging is done elsewhere ;)

Comment: Then don't `printStackTrace`

Comment: The Code is not finished, this is not the final product and the logging is handled with l4j in future, not implemented now

Answer (score 0):

If the object which implements your `get` method exists in a single instance, a `synchronized` keyword before the getter method declaration will be enough.

You may also be able to use a synchronized collection (like [ConcurrentHashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)) to store and access your data.

It is possible, however, that there exists a more efficient solution. As with all multithreaded synchronizations, you have to identify and isolate a critical section. Usually the shorter the critical section, the better the speed of the code.

Comment: Thank you, the get method exists in a single instance, but there is some logic inside calculating the IP-Address. It is using other methods from other classes, which are from the Java Framework (not my own classes).

Comment: Just post the `getMyIp()` method and we'll be able to say more.

Comment: I will post the method, but I think it is enough if you just know it's a complex method using different objects and classes from other libraries. Makes the question more complex than it is.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your code is Thread-safe so no additional work is needed here. You are not using shared mutable resources that can be shared along threads so should be no problem here.

Comment: I am Setting System properties, I am using the NetworkInterface class, which contains an Enumeration of Interfaces (could change while I am iterating trough it). There are shared mutable resources, if you ask me.

Comment: 1) You are setting sys props during ClassLoading - will happen only once. 2) No, this collection will not change. Any consecusive calls to `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` can give different results, but onece returned collection will not change.
3) I am no asking you, I am telling you because you clearly confusing mutable resources with different values

Comment: I was Setting the System-Property inside the getting method (which is static). I think it will get set every time the getter is called, do I oversee something? Or do you mean I should change that to an other place? About 2nd I can agree.